# Enable SSL in Loopback 4

Tags: node.js, loopback

I try to adapt this code from https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Server.html in my file application.ts as is

```
this.bootOptions = {
      controllers: {
        // Customize ControllerBooter Conventions here
        dirs: ['controllers'],
        extensions: ['.controller.js'],
        nested: true,
      },
      rest: {
        protocol: 'https',
        key: fs.readFileSync('./cert/my-site.com.key'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert/my-site.com.crt'),
      }
    };
```

I encounter problems when accessing my controller API
Tried nmap to see opened ports and curl but nothing seems to be served as https

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the answer

SSL settings should be set in index.ts as is

```
export async function main(options: ApplicationConfig = {}) {

  const optionssl = {
    rest: {
      protocol: 'https',
      key: fs.readFileSync('./cert/my-site.com.key'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert/my-site.com.crt'),
    }
  };

  const app = new MyApplication(optionssl);
```

application.ts should not be changed